# Yarn encounters 404 error installing local and remote packages for specific project folder

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-v2

I'm encountering the following message when installing packages:

```
YN0001: │ HTTPError: Response code 404 (Not Found)
    at se.<anonymous> (C:\Code\.yarn\releases\yarn-berry.cjs:23:10082)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)
```

This happens for both a local package using `yarn add ../my-package` or remote package (testing using `yarn add lodash`).

When I'm in another project on the same computer, the package is installed fine. What could be causing this?

Comment: As no answer was received I deleted all yarn / node_module folders and files except yarn.lock. That worked. No idea what was causing the initial issue though.

Answer (score 0):

This could be that a `yarn link` has been deleted. When making the symlink using yarn link, a `resolutions` field is added in `package.json`. Just having this link however is not adequate.